# editableSelect() does not fire after ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an ajax method that runs as soon as the page is loaded without listening to any event. The ajax fetches student ID from the database and shows the student ID in a select box. I want the select box to be editable (http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/). The function `$('#studentID').editableSelect();` runs completely fine when the options are hardcoded in the select tag. However, no data is shown in the selectbox when `$('#studentID').editableSelect();` is called and the data is fetched from the database.

Here is the code that is written in the JavaScript file

```
$('#studentID').editableSelect();

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'./public/api/studentID.php',
  success:function(html){
    $('#studentID').html(html);

  }
});
```

`#studentID` definition

```
<label for="studentID">ID</label>
<select id = "studentID" class="form-control">

</select>
```

php code

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli ("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

    $query = "SELECT `SID` FROM `student`  ORDER BY `SID` ";

    $result1= mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[0];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;

    $connection->close();
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: more code including `#studentID`definition, please

Comment: I have added the `#studentID` definition and the php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `editableSelect` into the `ajax.success` method. The problem is that you are initializeing an empty select element, and then inserting it the options with the asynchronous `ajax` method. The success will forever happen after the data will successfully loaded, and then you can initialize the select with any framework/library, including `editableSelect` that you want to.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'./public/api/studentID.php',
  success:function(html){
    let student_el = $('#studentID');
    student_el.html(html);
    student_el.editableSelect();
  }
});
```

EDIT:

you might not included the library in the right way, so for any case, here is the two ways to include it:

#### Inside the head tag

```
<head>
    <!--Include jQuery + you libraries...-->
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

#### Inside the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './public/api/studentID.php',
    success: function(html){
        let student_el = $('#studentID');
        student_el.html(html);
        $.getScript("https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js")
            .then(() => {
                student_el.editableSelect(); // Call this function after the script have been successfully loaded.
            });
        //student_el.editableSelect();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this before and it throws an error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: student_el.editableSelect is not a function`

Comment: @auditore try it now.

Comment: No luck. 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

`jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/working-files/path-to-jquery-editable-select?_=1538172432790 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Replace "path-to-jquery-editable-select" with the path to your library, like in the include. If you didn't download the library, it should look like this: `$.getScript("https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js");`

Comment: Getting back the initial error 
`Uncaught TypeError: student_el.editableSelect is not a function`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort to solve this. The code works great. However, when the no of options in the select box is huge, the page does not response and then crashes. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181001/discussion-between-korelk-and-auditore).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try calling editableSelect on your callback

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'./public/api/studentID.php',
  success:function(html){
   $('#studentID').html(html);
   $('#studentID').editableSelect();
  }
});
```

Comment: This throws an error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editableSelect is not a function`

Comment: Your select get's populated with options? Because it seems you're not returning anything from the server

Comment: Yes. Select gets populated.